# Is std::equal guaranteed to short circuit?

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison, language-lawyer

I would like to compare a nul-terminated string against a string literal. I hope to use `std::equal` and am curious if this code is well-defined according to the C++ standard:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

bool is_foo(const char *str) {
    const char *lit = "foo";
    return std::equal(lit, lit + 4, str);
}
```

If `std::equal` is guaranteed to stop at the first mismatch, then this code seems defined to me even if `str` has length < 3. If there is no such guarantee then I think this may dereference past the end of `str` resulting in UB.

What if anything does the C++ spec say about this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: AFAIK only length comparison is guaranteed for RandomAccessIterators; in practice, it'll most likely short-circuit.

Comment: There is absolutely no such guarantee. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M6c5MWhhe)

Comment: The standard states no such requirement.     It does describe upper limits (e.g. on the number of comparisons) but doesn't state requirements that will result in short-circuiting.   In practice, most implementations probably will short-circuit in some way - but how (or if) they do that is a quality of implementation concern, not a given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My reading of the C++ standard indicates that this is pedantically undefined behavior based on the following remark:

> Remarks: If last2 was not given in the argument list, it denotes first2 +
> (last1 - first1) below.

This is referring to overloads of `std::equal` that do not supply the second sequence's ending iterator. In this case this would not be a valid pointer, hence this is pedantically undefined behavior, given the following part of the specification:

> E be: pred(*i, *(first2 + (i - first1))) for the overloads with no parameter
> proj1;
>
> ...
>
> Returns: If last1 - first1 != last2 - first2, return false. Otherwise return
> true if E holds for every iterator i in the range [first1, last1) Otherwise,
> returns false.

I see nothing here that guarantees short circuit evaluation. The complexity does not seem to imply guaranteed short-circuit evaluation, either:

> Complexity:
>
> [ ... ]
>
> ... at most min(last1 - first1, last2 - first2) applications of ...

The "at most" part is not qualified in any way. Strictly interpreted this allows, but not requires, short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: I'd go further than _pedantically undefined_. It's reasonable for a standard library implementation to try and use wider comparison instructions (say 64 or 128 bits wide) if the arguments are aligned, and the arrays are simple integers.